# How to merge data from multiple dictionaries with repeating keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'a': '2', 'b': '10'}
dict2 = {'a': '25', 'b': '7'}
```

I need to save all the values for same key in a new dictionary.

The best i can do so far is: `defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': ['2', '25'], 'b': ['10', '7']})`

```
dd = defaultdict(list)
for d in (dict1, dict2):
    for key, value in d.items():
        dd[key].append(value)
print(dd)
```

that does not fully resolve the problem since a desirable result is:

```
a = {'dict1':'2', 'dict2':'25'}
b = {'dict2':'10', 'dict2':'7'}
```

Also i possibly would like to use new dictionary key same as initial dictionary name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086067/how-to-merge-data-from-multiple-dictionaries-with-repeating-keys/60086116#60086116) suggested, structuring your result as a nested dictionary will be easier:

```
{'a': {'dict1': '2', 'dict2': '25'}, 'b': {'dict1': '10', 'dict2': '7'}}
```

Which could be achieved with a *dict comprehension*:

```
{k: {"dict%d" % i: v2 for i, v2 in enumerate(v1, start=1)} for k, v1 in dd.items()}
```

If you prefer doing it without a comprehension, you could do this instead:

```
result = {}
for k, v1 in dd.items():
    inner_dict = {}

    for i, v2 in enumerate(v1, start=1):
        inner_dict["dict%d" % i] = v2

    result[k] = inner_dict
```

**Note:** This assumes you want to always want to keep the *"dict1"*, *"dict2"*,... key structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you're trying to cross the implementation boundary between a string value and a variable name.  This is almost always bad design.  Instead, start with all of your labels as string data:

```
table = {
    "dict1": {'a': '2',  'b': '10'},
    "dict2": {'a': '25', 'b': '7'}
}
```

... or, in terms of your original post:

```
table = {
    "dict1": dict1,
    "dict2": dict2
}
```

From here, you should be able to invert the levels to obtain

```
invert = {
    "a": {'dict1': '2',  'dict2': '25'},
    "b": {'dict2': '10', 'dict2': '7'}
}
```

Is that enough to get your processing where it needs to be?  Keeping the data in comprehensive dicts like this, will make it easier to iterate through the sub-dicts as needed.

Comment: that would be a work around, but table creation i this case seems a manual process is there a way to do it more automatically (it is acceptable not to use dict1 and dict2 (initial dictionary names) as new dictionary keys).